# Installing policycoreutils-python for container-selinux on RHEL

Tags: centos, rhel

I am trying to install:

```
sudo yum install -y http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/extras/x86_64/Packages/container-selinux-2.119.2-1.911c772.el7_8.noarch.rpm
```

But it gives me:

```
Error:
 Problem: conflicting requests
  - nothing provides policycoreutils-python needed by container-selinux-2:2.119.2-1.911c772.el7_8.noarch
```

Trying to install `policycoreutils-python` also fails:

```
yum install policycoreutils-python
No match for argument: policycoreutils-python
Error: Unable to find a match: policycoreutils-python
```

But I already have:

```
yum install policycoreutils-python-utils
Package policycoreutils-python-utils-2.9-24.el8.noarch is already installed.
```

Which I think contains `policycoreutils-python`? But I am not sure how to resolve this error and install `container-selinux-2.119.2-1.911c772.el7_8.noarch.rpm`.

My OS is `Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.8`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to install the RHEL7 RPM. A perfectly suitable RHEL8 RPM is present.

This fails:

```bash
[root@rhel88-test ~]# yum install -y http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/extras/x86_64/Packages/container-selinux-2.119.2-1.911c772.el7_8.noarch.rpm
Updating Subscription Management repositories.
Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8 for x86_64 - AppStream (RPMs)                                                                                                                30 MB/s |  58 MB     00:01
Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8 for x86_64 - BaseOS (RPMs)                                                                                                                   31 MB/s |  62 MB     00:02
Last metadata expiration check: 0:00:16 ago on Fri 28 Jul 2023 07:05:26 AM EDT.
container-selinux-2.119.2-1.911c772.el7_8.noarch.rpm                                                                                                                   838 kB/s |  40 kB     00:00
Error:
 Problem: conflicting requests
  - nothing provides policycoreutils-python needed by container-selinux-2:2.119.2-1.911c772.el7_8.noarch
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best candidate packages)
```

But this works just fine:

```
[root@rhel88-test ~]# dnf install container-selinux
Updating Subscription Management repositories.
Last metadata expiration check: 0:00:33 ago on Fri 28 Jul 2023 07:05:26 AM EDT.
Dependencies resolved.
=======================================================================================================================================================================================================
 Package                                  Architecture                  Version                                                          Repository                                               Size
=======================================================================================================================================================================================================
Installing:
 container-selinux                        noarch                        2:2.205.0-2.module+el8.8.0+18438+15d3aa65                        rhel-8-for-x86_64-appstream-rpms                         64 k
Enabling module streams:
 container-tools                                                        rhel8

Transaction Summary
=======================================================================================================================================================================================================
Install  1 Package

Total download size: 64 k
Installed size: 62 k
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Downloading Packages:
container-selinux-2.205.0-2.module+el8.8.0+18438+15d3aa65.noarch.rpm                                                                                                   294 kB/s |  64 kB     00:00
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total                                                                                                                                                                  291 kB/s |  64 kB     00:00
Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8 for x86_64 - AppStream (RPMs)                                                                                                               4.9 MB/s | 5.0 kB     00:00
Running transaction check
Transaction check succeeded.
Running transaction test
Transaction test succeeded.
Running transaction
  Preparing        :                                                                                                                                                                               1/1
  Running scriptlet: container-selinux-2:2.205.0-2.module+el8.8.0+18438+15d3aa65.noarch                                                                                                            1/1
  Installing       : container-selinux-2:2.205.0-2.module+el8.8.0+18438+15d3aa65.noarch                                                                                                            1/1
  Running scriptlet: container-selinux-2:2.205.0-2.module+el8.8.0+18438+15d3aa65.noarch                                                                                                            1/1
  Verifying        : container-selinux-2:2.205.0-2.module+el8.8.0+18438+15d3aa65.noarch                                                                                                            1/1
Installed products updated.

Installed:
  container-selinux-2:2.205.0-2.module+el8.8.0+18438+15d3aa65.noarch

Complete!
```